# php > SimpleXMLElement > '&' Symbol

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having problems using the `&` in xml strings created by php's `SimpleXMLElement`. For example the following:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><links></links>");
$xml->addChild("url","https://www.somewhere.com?a=1&b=2");
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

gives me when run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<links><url>https://www.somewhere.com?a=1</url></links>
```

I have already tried:

```
...
$xml->addChild("url","https://www.somewhere.com?a=1&amp;b=2");
...
```

and got:

```
...
<links><url>https://www.somewhere.com?a=1&amp;b=2</url></links>
```

how do I get:

```
...
<links><url>https://www.somewhere.com?a=1&b=2</url></links>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the escaped &amp;?

Comment: not to sure if the server I'm sending the xml file to will like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. That is illegal XML: the `&` character *must* be escaped ([XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#syntax)).